# Is it possible to draw this equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to draw an equilateral triangle which does not pass through the center of the circle(I mean the center of the circle does not lie within the boundaries of the triangle)?The given conditions are that the vertices of the triangle will touch the circumference of the circle. I assume it is not but cannot prove it. Please help.

Comment: What circle? Your question does not have enough information to be answered.

Comment: Draw any equilateral triangle $ABC$. Then translate $ABC$ by twice the length of $AB$ to obtain $A'B'C'$. Whatever your circle, at least one of $ABC$, $A'B'C'$ does not contain its center in its inside

Comment: @wltrup-Sorry for the incomplete question.I have edited it.

Comment: This question is utterly unclear, or totally trivial: There is basically just one equilateral triangle $T$ whose vertices lie on a given circle (Or what is meant by "touching the circle"?). The midpoint of the circle, being the centroid of the triangle, of course lies in the interior of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

The center of the circumscribed circle is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the three sides.
For an equilateral triangle, these perpendicular bisectors are at the same time the angular bisectors, which determine the center of the *in*scribed circle. The latter is always an *interior* point of a triangle, henc for an equilateral triangle so is the center of the circumscribed circle.